# Find all $2\times 2$ matrices $A$ such that $E_7 = \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find all $2\times 2$ matrices $A$ such that $E_7 = \mathbb{R}^2$, where $E_7$ is the eigenspace associated to the eigenvalue $7$.

Can someone give me a concise way of completing the problem?

I know that $\det(A-\lambda I_2) = \lambda^2-(\operatorname{tr}A)\lambda+\det A$, but the problem seems more difficult that just finding $\det(A-7I_2) = 49-7(\operatorname{tr}A)+\det A$.

Comment: What do you mean by $E_7$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael The eigenvector for eigenvalue $7$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Look the edit for a much simpler proof) Let $B\in \Bbb R^{2\times 2}$ a matrix which has $7$ as eigenvalue and $\Bbb R^2$ as associated eigenspace. Since $\dim(E_7) = 2 = \dim(\Bbb R^2)$, $B$ is [diagonalizable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Characterization) and so it can be written in the form $B=PDP^{-1}$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with he
eigenvalues of $B$ and $P$ is invertible. In particular we must have $D = 7I_2$ where $I_2$ is the identity matrix. But then $D$ commutes with any matrix and so we have $B=PDP^{-1}=PP^{-1}D = D = 7I_2$.

**EDIT**:
Let $A\in \Bbb R^{2\times 2}$ a matrix which has $7$ as eigenvalue and $\Bbb R^2$ as associated eigenspace. Then $\{\vec{e}_1,\vec{e}_2\}=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ is a basis of $E_7$ so $A\vec{e}_1=7\vec{e}_1$ and $A\vec{e}_2 = 7\vec{e}_2$. Now let $\vec{v}=(v_1,v_2) \in \Bbb R^2$, then $v = v_1 \vec{e}_1+v_2\vec{e}_2$ and so $$Av = A(v_1 \vec{e}_1+v_2\vec{e}_2) = v_1 A\vec{e}_1+v_2A\vec{e}_2 = 7v_1 \vec{e}_1+7v_2\vec{e}_2 = 7(v_1 \vec{e}_1+v_2\vec{e}_2) = 7v$$
It follows that $Aw = 7w$ for all $w\in \Bbb R^2$, i.e. $A = 7I_2$.

Comment: I've gotten a matrix of the form $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & 7-a\\
c & 7-c \end{array} \right)$, where $a,c\not = 0,7$. Does this seem right?

Comment: Actually, maybe not. Can $U$ be any invertible matrix?

Comment: @Carley See my edit, it should answer your question. But yes $U$ can be any invertible matrix, it's just a change of basis.

Comment: What if we just solve the system $A\vec{v} = \lambda \vec{v}$ where $A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b \\
c & d  \\
 \end{array} \right), \vec{v} \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 \\
1  \\
 \end{array} \right), \lambda = 7$?

Comment: @Carley $\operatorname{span}(v) \neq \Bbb R^2$. You must have $Av=7v, Aw = 7w$ and $v,w\neq 0$ linearly independent for $E_7 = \Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I'm having trouble finding $P$. Should I just use a general matrix, like $A$ in my last comment (since $A = PBP^{-1}$)?

Comment: @Carley You won't find explicitly $P$ since $B$ is not explicit before the end of the proof. My proof shows:
Let $B$ be any matrix such that $E_7 = \Bbb R^2$, then $B$ must be 7 times the identity matrix. Have you looked at the wikipedia link about diagonlaization?

Comment: Oh, so the answer is just $7I_2$. Sorry, I didn't read your edit clearly.

Comment: @Carley exactly :)

Comment: @Carley I added a simpler proof :) that is not requiring explicitly diagonalisation.

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler: by definition $A x = \lambda x = \lambda I x$ for $x$ in the eigenspace $E_\lambda$, so if that eigenspace is the whole space $A = \lambda I$.